# mySQL Error while migrating WordPress Website locally

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am trying to migrate a live WordPress site to my localhost environment. And I believe that the PHP version on current hosting server is higher than my localhost environment version, which is causing some issue while migrating. As I don't know much about SQL code as well as how to interpret the error log, can you guide me on what I should be doing to rectify the error?

Followed is the error message I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\functions.php:60
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-settings.php(425): include()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-config.php(89): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\shag\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\functions.php on line 60
```

Comment: As far as I know `mysql_*` functions was deleted from PHP 7. Check your version of PHP.

Comment: Can you check the version of PHP in the server? As what the comment of @ViacheslavZhabonos says, mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP4.3 and totally removed in PHP7 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thanks @Ronald it is 5.5 on the server and it's 7.0 on my localhost. If I upgrade the server version to 7.0 and bundle the package, will it help?

Comment: Lower on the server than in the localhost? But it's working on the localhost?

Comment: @Aroganz Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: @Ronald Yes lower on the client's server. But I managed to migrate to my personal server which had the same version instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true);
```

Would you please define above code in your `wp-config.php`? And check it. I think it's helpful for you.